# EE 2.8.1 Remove index.php - XML sitemaps not working

Tags: xml

I'm using the EllisLab official method for removing index.php from the url as described in the docs:

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html

However that seems to have broken access to the xml sitemaps I have created using NSM Better Meta as they are not rendering at all. I've also tried to generate sitemaps using the Sitemap module by PutYourLights On - (Ben Croker) and that also fails.

This is for EE 2.8.1. Sites running EE 2.7.3 don't seem to have this problem

Is this an issue with the htaccess code?

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error? What URL are the sitemaps supposed to be located it? What do you mean that the PutYourLightsOn module fails? Are there errors? More details would help.

Comment: Hi Jeremy. Thanks for the response. Bu "fails" I mean that both methods return a blank file. No errors are returned. Files are located at mydomain.com/xml-sitemaps/news etc

Comment: can you provide a link to you the site? if you prefer to keep it private then please email me and i'll try to troubleshoot the issue for you.